# Get absolute path to workspace directory in Jenkins Pipeline plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I'm currently doing some evaluation on the Jenkins Pipeline plugin (formerly know as Workflow plugin).
Reading the documentation I found out that I currently cannot retriev the workspace path using
`env.WORKSPACE`:

> The following variables are currently unavailable inside a workflow script:
>
> NODE_LABELS
>
> WORKSPACE
>
> SCM-specific variables such as SVN_REVISION

Is there any other way how to get the absolute path to the current workspace? I need this running some test which in turn gets some parameter (absolute path to some executable file).
I already tried using `new File("").absolutePath()` inside a `@NonCPS` section but looks like the non-CPS stuff gets always executed on the master.

Does anybody have a clue how to get this path *without* running some batch script which stores the path into some file which later on can be read in again?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Since version 2.5 of the [Pipeline Nodes and Processes Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Nodes+and+Processes+Plugin) (a component of the Pipeline plugin, installed by default), the `WORKSPACE` environment variable is available again. This version was released on 2016-09-23, so it should be available on all up-to-date Jenkins instances.

#### Example

```
node('label'){
    // now you are on slave labeled with 'label'
    def workspace = WORKSPACE
    // ${workspace} will now contain an absolute path to job workspace on slave

    workspace = env.WORKSPACE
    // ${workspace} will still contain an absolute path to job workspace on slave

    // When using a GString at least later Jenkins versions could only handle the env.WORKSPACE variant:
    echo "Current workspace is ${env.WORKSPACE}"

    // the current Jenkins instances will support the short syntax, too:
    echo "Current workspace is $WORKSPACE"

}
```

Comment: A quick note for anyone who is using bat in the job and needs to access Workspace:

It won't work.

$WORKSPACE https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33511 as mentioned here only works with PowerShell. Answer for reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57089239/4269078

Comment: Please see my answer below how to access WORKSPACE as property of the pipeline itself on Jenkins 2.222.3, Build Pipeline Plugin 1.5.8, Pipeline: Nodes and Processes 2.35: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62216903/1620597)

Answer (score 61):

**Note**: this solution works only if the slaves have the same directory structure as the master. `pwd()` will return the workspace directory on the master due to [JENKINS-33511](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33511).

I used to do it using `pwd()` functionality of pipeline plugin. So, if you need to get a workspace on slave, you may do smth like this:

```
node('label'){
    //now you are on slave labeled with 'label'
    def workspace = pwd()
    //${workspace} will now contain an absolute path to job workspace on slave 
}
```

Comment: Damn. Probably need some glasses. Totally missed that there's pwd() available. That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: And, yet, according to the discussion in [this ticket](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33511), `pwd()` will return the work directory of the master, not the node you are on.

Comment: A fact I just confirmed by myself. `pwd()` will _not_ work on slaves, unless they happen to have the same directory structure as the master.

Comment: It seems the linked Jenkins ticket has been resolved?

Answer (score 23):

"WORKSPACE" environment variable works for the latest version of Jenkins Pipeline. You can use this in your Jenkins file: "${env.WORKSPACE}"

Sample use below:

```
def files = findFiles glob: '**/reports/*.json'
for (def i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
jsonFilePath = "${files[i].path}"       
jsonPath = "${env.WORKSPACE}" + "/" + jsonFilePath
echo jsonPath
```

hope that helps!!

Comment: Please note that the accepted answer as well mentions that the `WORKSPACE` variable now is available: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43137597/4279361

Comment: I looked into that answer but it did not have a code sample. So I still had to do some research before implementation. I don't mind the down vote but I hope my answer helps someone immediately by just copying the syntax.

Comment: @anuj0901 I totally agree, answers with code samples should be the accepted answers, not text only answers. Thank you for the additional content.

Answer (score 1):

For me WORKSPACE was a valid property of the pipeline itself. So when I handed over `this` to a Groovy method as parameter `context` from the pipeline script itself, I was able to access the correct value using `"... ${context.WORKSPACE} ..."`

(on Jenkins 2.222.3, Build Pipeline Plugin 1.5.8, Pipeline: Nodes and Processes 2.35)

Comment: Thanks for the note. Would you see a benefit to favor `context.WORKSPACE` over `env.WORKSPACE`? Is there some documentation available about the `context` object?