# How to retrieve current workspace using Jenkins Pipeline Groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to get the current workspace of my Jenkins build using a Groovy pipeline script:

```
node('master') {
    // PULL IN ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
    // Jenkins makes these variables available for each job it runs
    def buildNumber = env.BUILD_NUMBER
    def workspace = env.WORKSPACE
    def buildUrl = env.BUILD_URL

    // PRINT ENVIRONMENT TO JOB
    echo "workspace directory is ${workspace}"
    echo "build URL is ${env.BUILD_URL}"
}
```

It returns:

```
[Pipeline] Allocate node : Start
Running on master in /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/test/workspace
[Pipeline] node {
[Pipeline] echo
workspace directory is null
[Pipeline] echo
build URL is http://localhost:8080/job/test/5/
[Pipeline] } //node
[Pipeline] Allocate node : End
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-33511

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get absolute path to workspace directory in Jenkins Pipeline plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36934028/get-absolute-path-to-workspace-directory-in-jenkins-pipeline-plugin)

Answer (score 48):

For me just `${WORKSPACE}` worked without even initializing the variable `workspace`.

Comment: me too but only with uppercase `${WORKSPACE}` works, `${workspace}` does NOT

Comment: `${WORKSPACE}` works for me too and not `${workspace}`. `${workspace}` is taken as `class workspace`

Answer (score 7):

There is no variable included for that yet, so you have to use shell-out-read-file method:

```
sh 'pwd > workspace'
workspace = readFile('workspace').trim()
```

Or (if running on master node):

```
workspace = pwd()
```

Comment: Don't forget to trim() your readFile() result, otherwise you will end up with a newline out of nowhere.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can also execute the pwd() function on the particular node:

```
node {
    def PWD = pwd();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A quick note for anyone who is using `bat` in the job and needs to access Workspace:

**It won't work**.

`$WORKSPACE` https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33511 as mentioned here only works with PowerShell. So your code should have `powershell` for execution

```
 stage('Verifying Workspace') {
  powershell label: '', script: 'dir $WORKSPACE'
}
```

Comment: this sounds as its only working that way on Windows systems.

Answer (score 4):

I have successfully used as shown below in Jenkinsfile:

```
steps {
  script {
    def reportPath = "${WORKSPACE}/target/report"
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The key is that, this works if used within double quotes instead of single quotes, below is my code and this worked!

```
script {
    echo 'Entering Stage - Nexus Upload'
    def artefactPath = "${WORKSPACE}/build/deploy/identityiq.war"   
    echo "printing the path ${artefactPath}"
}
```

Comment: Groovy does not interpolate strings in single quotes `'${WORKSPACE}'`, only in double quotes: `"${WORKSPACE}"`. Similarly it will interpolate strings in triple double quotes `"""${WORKSPACE}"""`, but not in triple single quotes `'''${WORKSPACE}'''`.  See https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This is where you can find the answer in the [job-dsl-plugin code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/master/docs/Extending-the-DSL.md).

Basically you can do something like this:

```
readFileFromWorkspace('src/main/groovy/com/groovy/jenkins/scripts/enable_safehtml.groovy')
```

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins pipeline script, I am using

```
targetDir = workspace
```

Works perfect for me. No need to use ${WORKSPACE}