# Store current workspace path in variable for a later stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using the declarative syntax for my pipeline, and would like to store the path to the workspace being used on one of my stages, so that same path can be used in a later stage.

I have seen I can call `pwd()` to get the current directory, but how do I assign to a variable to be used between stages?

**EDIT**

I have tried to do this by defining by own custom variable and using like so with the ws directive:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'master' }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        script {
          def workspace = pwd()
        }
        sh '''
          npm install
          bower install
          gulp set-staging-node-env
          gulp prepare-staging-files
          gulp webpack
        '''
        stash includes: 'dist/**/*', name: 'builtSources'
        stash includes: 'config/**/*', name: 'appConfig'
        node('Protractor') {
          dir('/opt/foo/deploy/') {
            unstash 'builtSources'
            unstash 'appConfig'
          }
        }        
      }
    }
    stage('Unit Tests') {
      steps {
        parallel (
          "Jasmine": {
            node('master') {
              ws("${workspace}"){
                sh 'gulp karma-tests-ci'
              }
            }
          },
          "Mocha": {
            node('master') {
              ws("${workspace}"){
                sh 'gulp mocha-tests'
              }
            }
          }
        )
      }
      post {
        success {
          sh 'gulp combine-coverage-reports'
          sh 'gulp clean-lcov'
          publishHTML(target: [
            allowMissing: false,
            alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
            keepAll: false,
            reportDir: 'test/coverage',
            reportFiles: 'index.html',
            reportName: 'Test Coverage Report'
          ])
        }
      }
    }
    }
}
```

In the Jenkins build console, I see this happens:

```
[Jasmine] Running on master in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/_Pipelines_IACT-Jenkinsfile-UL3RGRZZQD3LOPY2FUEKN5XCY4ZZ6AGJVM24PLTO3OPL54KTJCEQ@2
[Pipeline] [Jasmine] {
[Pipeline] [Jasmine] ws
[Jasmine] Running in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/_Pipelines_IACT-Jenkinsfile-UL3RGRZZQD3LOPY2FUEKN5XCY4ZZ6AGJVM24PLTO3OPL54KTJCEQ@2@2
```

The original workspace allocated from the first stage is actually `_Pipelines_IACT-Jenkinsfile-UL3RGRZZQD3LOPY2FUEKN5XCY4ZZ6AGJVM24PLTO3OPL54KTJCEQ`

So it doesnt look like it working, what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Stage-One') {
            steps {
                echo 'StageOne.....'
                script{ name = 'StackOverFlow'}
            }
        }
        stage('Stage-Two'){
            steps{
                echo 'StageTwo.....'
                echo "${name}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above prints `StackOverFlow` in `StageTwo` for `echo "${name}`"
You can also use `sh "echo ${env.WORKSPACE}"` to get The absolute path of the directory assigned to the build as a workspace.

Comment: Thanks, I have actually used a different approach, see my updated question. However it still doesnt seem to work, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could put the value into an [environment variable](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/) like described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38783622/7926064)

```
CURRENT_PATH= sh (
    script: 'pwd',
    returnStdout: true
).trim()
```

Which version are you running? [Maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43137597/7926064) you can just assign the `WORKSPACE` variable to an environment var?

Or did i totally misunderstand and [this is](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33893) what you are looking for?

Comment: I think assigning to a variable is the correct way to go from what I have read elsewhere, however I cannot get it to work. See my edit on my original question