# Jenkins pipeline - how to get git file path

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

This is a snippet from my `Jenkinsfile`:

```
        stage('Checkout project') {
            checkout scm
        }
        scalaImage = docker.image('<myNexus>/centos-sbt:2.11.8')
        stage('Test project') {
            docker.withRegistry('<myNexus>', 'jenkins-nexus') {
                scalaImage.inside('-v /var/lib/jenkins/.ivy2:/root/.ivy2') { c ->
                    sh 'sbt clean test'
                }
            }
        }
```

When I look in the docs for what `.inside` does I find:

1. Automatically grab a slave and a workspace (no extra node block is
   required).
2. Pull the requested image to the Docker server (if not
   already cached).
3. Start a container running that image.
4. Mount the Jenkins workspace as a “volume” inside the container, using the same **file path**

My question is regarding the last two words of point 4. Is there a way to get the file path that the plugin is using to mount the code into the docker container?

Thank you.

Comment: `env.WORKSPACE` will give you the path to what is being mounted. By convention right now, it is mapped to a directory of the same exact name in the container but that may have changed in recent versions. This currently sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36934028/get-absolute-path-to-workspace-directory-in-jenkins-pipeline-plugin): `pwd()` is what I needed.

```
node('label'){
    //now you are on slave labeled with 'label'
    def workspace = pwd()
    //${workspace} will now contain an absolute path to job workspace on slave 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [CloudBees plugin](https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide/index.html#docker-workflow). It will automatically mount your current Workspace to the docker image.

Comment: That's exactly the problem. I don't know the name of the workspace that the plugin is mounting so if I want to mount something there myself - like a cache directory for sbt - I cannot do it.

Comment: its always pwd which is mounted which is ${WORKSPACE}/scmDir. If you want to mount custom volumes, pass them as map. Kindly check this https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline-lib/blob/master/vars/executeDockerNative.groovy/#L11