# Jenkins doesn't see existing file in workspace

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to read some file in a certain job.
Using Script Console in Jenkins I see the follow:

- Jenkins can access the necessary build in a job

`file = new File ("${Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('Build mac pipelines/sand box').lastBuild}")`

The result will be:

`Result: Build mac pipelines/sand box #44`

- But when I try to read the file groovy1.txt like this:

`file = new File ("${Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('Build mac pipelines/sand box').lastBuild}/groovy1.txt").text`

then Jenkins can't find groovy1.txt file

`Build mac pipelines/sand box #44/groovy1.txt (No such file or directory)`

It happens while such file exists, screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Why it happens and how to read the file ?

Answer (score 0):

The workspace path does not contain the build number.

Each build uses the same workspace.

If possible look at the filesystem of the machine, where Jenkins is installed.

**EDIT**

If I remember correctly you don't even need the absolute path of the workspace, you could try `file = new File ("./groovy1.txt").text`.

Please check also here for some suggestions: [Get absolute path to workspace directory in Jenkins Pipeline plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36934028/get-absolute-path-to-workspace-directory-in-jenkins-pipeline-plugin)

Comment: ok, the new command will be `file = new File ("${Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('Build mac pipelines/sand box')}/groovy1.txt").text`  and the result `java.io.FileNotFoundException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob@301b99ab[Build mac pipelines/sand box]/groovy1.txt (No such file or directory)`

Comment: I need absolute path, because I'm going to read file from another job.

Comment: Ok, then you should check the link I provided. In addition I don't think the hierarchy `Build mac pipelines/sand box` provided in the web interface matches with the actual file system.